# How to solve non-"cross-damping off" Linblad equation in QuTiP?

Tags: programming, optical-quantum-computing, qutip, master-equation

As I understand from the official QuTiP guidlines, it is only capable of solving "cross-damping off" Master Equation in form:

$\dot{\rho(t)} = -\dfrac{i}{\hbar}[H(t),\rho(t)] + \sum\limits_n\dfrac{1}{2}\left[ C_n\rho(t)C_n^{\dagger} - \rho(t)C_n^{\dagger}C_n - C_n^{\dagger}C_n\rho(t) \right].$

Where $C_n$ are collapse operators. However when we need to consider cross-damping, the ME takes the form like:

$\dot{\rho(t)} = -\dfrac{i}{\hbar}[H(t),\rho(t)] + \sum\limits_{i,j}\dfrac{1}{2}\left[ C_i\rho(t)C_j^{\dagger} - \rho(t)C_i^{\dagger}C_j - C_i^{\dagger}C_j\rho(t) \right].$

Is QuTiP capable of solving this? And how one can manage to code this if it is?

Answer (score 2):

In QuTiP, one can construct generalized dissipators with the `lindblad_dissipator` function listed under "Superoperators and Liouvillians" [here](https://qutip.org/docs/latest/apidoc/functions.html).  You can pass in separate operators to act from the left and right:
\begin{align}
D[a,b] = a\rho b^\dagger - \frac{1}{2}a^\dagger b \rho - \frac{1}{2} \rho a b^\dagger
\end{align}
Then, in the master equation solver `mesolve`, if you pass in such dissipators in the collapse operator argument, QuTiP will detect superoperator contributions and add them directly to the total Liouvillian.